# フィード(RSS)　取得・検出 プログラムの仕組み（PHPorJAVA）

Tags: php

任意のサイトのURLを入力することで、そのサイトにフィード（RSS,atom）があるかを調べ
ある場合はそのフィードを返すプログラムを考えています。
具体的には下記です。

http://berss.com/feed/Find.aspx
http://php.s307.xrea.com/

これらのプログラムはおおよそどのような仕組みで動いているのでしょうか？
どのような手法・考えで実装しているかが知りたいです。

考えたものは下記ですが意図した結果になりませんでした。

・ドメインから　/feed/ ,/index.rdf, /?xml, /feed/rss/,
 など「良くあるfeedのURLを付け足して総当りで調べる
→「よくあるURL」以外をどう探すのか

・Googleにて　上記よくあるURLを付け足して検索
　→検索結果に出てこなかった

Comment: `<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml"`, `<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml"`, `<link rel="meta" type="application/rdf+xml"` あたりを調べる。

Comment: すいません、もう少し詳しくお願いします。
「調べる」とはその言葉の仕様を調べるのか、Google検索に絡めて引っ張ってくる事なのか、それとも別の意図なのか不明です。

Comment: `link`タグの`type`属性を調べて上記のタイプのウチの一つだったら`href`属性からファイル名（これがフィードのアドレス）を取り出す。という意味です。（それで取り出せないような場合はそのHTMLのtypeが別のタイプだったのかを調べて自分のマッチングに加える）

Answer (score 1):

通常、[RSS Autodiscovery](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-autodiscovery)という仕様にもとづいてURLを取得することが多いと思います。